# Clarification of Fuchs's theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is Fuchs's theorem
[image]

My professor has been saying the last couple of classes that if $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are polynomials, then the second order differential equation converges everywhere. He hasn't specified the theorem but I've been trying to look more in detail about this statement he mentioned and I would like to know if Fuchs's theorem is the theorem that implies this idea.

In addition, what does it mean when it is said "if both $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ have taylor series" I know what taylor series are but I'm not too familiar with their purpose. In addition, anyone have any idea how to find $(-r,r)$ or the interval?

Comment: I would emphasize that the series of $p,q$ must converge to the indicated functions, that is $p,q$ are **analytic.** The standard examples of functions with a series that does not converge to the function are  $p(0)=0,$ otherwise $$ p(t) = e^{-1/t^2}, $$ and the more disturbing  $q(0)=0,$ otherwise $$ q(t) = e^{-1/t^2} \sin \left( \frac{1}{t} \right). $$ Perhaps the phrase "Taylor Series" indicates analyticity in your book, you should check. I do not think of that as standard usage, so look for more context, especially just before your quoted theorem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchs%27_theorem